# How can I tell when a UIWebView has finished drawing to a context?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, cgcontext, core-graphics

In my code I'm trying to show a `UIWebView` as a page is loading, and then, when it's done, capture an image from the web view to cache and display later (so I don't have to reload and render the web page).

I have something along the lines of:

```
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(…);
[[webView layer] renderInContext:context];

CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

The problem I'm running into is that, due to `UIWebView`'s tiling, sometimes only half of the page is rendered to the context by the time I capture the image.

Is there a way to detect or block on `UIWebView`'s background rendering thread so that I can get the image only after all of the rendering has finished?

---

**UPDATE:** It may be that thread race conditions were a red herring (it's unclear from the documentation, at any rate, whether `UIWebView`'s custom layer or a `CATiledLayer` in general blocks on its background threads).

This may instead have been an invalidation issue (despite several sorts of calls to `setNeedsDisplay` on both the `UIWebView` and its layer). Changing the bounds of the `UIWebView` before rendering it appears to have eliminated the "not drawing the whole thing" problem.

I still ran into a problem where a few tiles were being drawn at the old scale, but calling `renderInContext:` twice seems to have mitigated that sufficiently.

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView is probably using a CATiledLayer or custom derivative.  You may be able to replace the layer with something of your own choosing such as a simple CALayer which does not do threaded drawing.  Replace the layer before you start loading content.

If replacing the layer with a standard CALayer does not work, you may have to make your own subclass that emulates the behavior of a CATiledLayer without actually being threaded.

Edit:

From CATiledLayer.h

```
/* Note: do not attempt to directly modify the `contents' property of
 * an CATiledLayer object - doing so will effectively turn it into a
 * regular CALayer. */
```

So you may just be able to set the contents to nil before calling `renderInContext:`